# Clone Dropdown Not Working as Expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

I'm trying to do one Jquery Code, which add (clone) Dropdown and Also can remove One by One, (From bottom to top.) Here Is My **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtJ9L/2/)**
.

M Trying to do that when user click on **Add** then query clone dropdown and alos display "Remove Button" Beside that Cloned element so we can remove that, But at list One Element Should be Present and it can not be deleted.

**My Jquery Code**

```
var countClone = 0;
$('#btnDel1Clon').click(function(){
    //alert(countClone);
    if (countClone == "1")
    {
        $( '#btnDel1Clon' ).css( 'display', 'none' );
        $('#test').remove(); 
    }
    else
    {
        $('#test').remove(); 
        countClone -= 1;
    }
});
$('#btnAdd1Clone').click(function(){
    countClone += 1;
    $('#test').clone().appendTo('#input11');
    $( '#btnDel1Clon' ).attr( 'style', 'display:"";' );
});
```

**HTML Code**

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="input11" class="clonedInput1 " style="margin-bottom: 15px!important; width:247px; float:none;">
              <div class="formRight" ><select><option>Value</option><option>Value</option><option>Value</option><option>Value</option><option>Value</option>
              </select>
              </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td valign="bottom" style="padding-bottom:15px;" class="btnspicalbtn">
            <div style="float:left;">
               <span class="floatleft">
                  <input id="btnAdd1Clone" type="button" value="Add"  class="iconadd1" title="Add More"/>
               </span> 
               <span class="floatleft brdleftinput" style="margin-left:8px;">
                  <input id="btnDel1Clon" type="button" value="Remove" style="display:none" class="iconremove" title="Remove" />
               </span>
            </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store clone of `#test` in some where and change `id` to `class` Like this:

JS:

```
var cloneTest = $('.test').clone();
var countClone = 0;

$('#btnDel1Clon').click(function(){
    //alert(countClone);
    var lastTest = $('.test').last();
    if (countClone == "1")
    {
        $( '#btnDel1Clon' ).css( 'display', 'none' );
        lastTest .remove(); 
    }
    else
    {
        lastTest.remove(); 
        countClone -= 1;
    }
});
$('#btnAdd1Clone').click(function(){
    countClone += 1;
    cloneTest.clone().appendTo('#input11');
    $( '#btnDel1Clon' ).attr( 'style', 'display:"";' );
});
```

HTML

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="input11" class="clonedInput1 " style="margin-bottom: 15px!important; width:247px; float:none;">
                <div class="formRight">
                    <select class="test">
                        <option>Value</option>
                        <option>Value</option>
                        <option>Value</option>
                        <option>Value</option>
                        <option>Value</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td valign="bottom" style="padding-bottom:15px;" class="btnspicalbtn">
            <div style="float:left;">
                <span class="floatleft">
                    <input id="btnAdd1Clone" type="button" value="Add" class="iconadd1" title="Add More" />
                </span>
                <span class="floatleft brdleftinput" style="margin-left:8px;">
                    <input id="btnDel1Clon" type="button" value="Remove" style="display:none" class="iconremove" title="Remove" />
                </span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Workable link: http://jsfiddle.net/bobkhin/Wgz36/

Comment: It Should Remove Last added dorp down first. Currently it remove first

Answer (score 1):

The code can't find the $('#test'), so it can't be cloned or be appended to the dom tree

Comment: If your counter starts from 1, your code can work as you expect.